# Is it possible to Wait "Document Set" level Workflow,until the "Document" has been uploaded to the related "Document Set"?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2016, document-set

Here I need to hold the "Document Set" level Workflow, until the first document has been uploaded to that "Document Set".

Is it possible to achieve using OOB or we need Custom Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no “Document set” level workflow in SharePoint.

I am afraid that it is not possible to achieve it by OOB workflow.

There is a workaround.

You could create a list workflow and then call http web service to check if there is document in the document set.

The “Call HTTP web service” is only available in workflow 2013.

More reference:

[Call HTTP Web Service Using SharePoint Designer 2013 (SPD).](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/58e23e/call-http-web-service-using-sharepoint-designer-2013-spd/)

Comment: Yes i've done this using rest api calls. Anyhow Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If the reply is helpful to you, you could accept the reply as answer